# How to set up a git repo with part of the code located in totally different floder from the repo working tree?

Tags: git, github

For example, I have git repo set up at D:\repo
Then I have some code which is part of the repo which is located in D:\other_code
I hope to include D:\other_code into the repo and push to GitHub as a whole.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "include"? Are you describing a worktree? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Comment: You can carry the the other_code as a branch and `git worktree add` the other_code dir for it.

Comment: @jthill I tried `git worktree add`  to do the job. But the command seems to copy everything located in D:\repo into D:\other_code. It also needs a specific branch to use worktree if I understand it right. What I expect is that different code resides in different folders. They are all parts of the same branch in one repo. Is this possible?

Comment: @matt By "include", I mean `.git` locates in D:\repo which is the root of the repo. And I also need D:\other_code to be as part of the repo in order to push and pull both of them together. Is this possible?

Comment: That still sounds like a worktree. They will not "push or pull both of them together"; there's no way to do that, unless you could make a symlink out of the working folder to some other folder (don't even know if that would work, I kind of doubt it). And if, as you say in a comment, they are all "parts of one branch", then no, that isn't going to happen.